# JavaScript Find a Variable String and Save it Into Another Variable

Tags: javascript

**Language:**     JavaScript or JS

**Issue Site:**   Vertix.io

**Goal:**         Show player health next to name tags

**Problem:**
I am trying to turn the player health into a separate variable, but I don't know how to separate it from the other settings. I code in different languages but I am relatively new to JavaScript. I am trying to make a script for a game that adds the players health next to their name. I am able to change the player name but don't know how to get the health value. I found a way to get only the alive players, but I don't know how to get an individual health value of a player. Here is the code I put together to get the alive players:

```
gameObjects.filter(function (o) {
   return o.type === 'player' && o.dead === false && o.name !== player.name;
});
```

But I still don't know how to grab the health value from the alive players. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Images:**

What I need (the Health Value):
[image: Image1]

What I have (Only the alive  players):
[image: Image2]

Comment: Your `filter` operation doesn't take any entries out of the players objects. How can that be possible?

Comment: you need to assign the return value of `filter()` to a variable, it doesn't modify the array it's given.

Comment: Doesn't `o.health` return what you want?

Comment: Barmar, I want to find the other player's health, not my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using the following method:

```
gameObjects.filter(function (o) {
 console.log(
 {
   "health":o.health,
   "name":o.name
  }
 ) // or change the console.log to what you need to do.
 return o.type === 'player' && o.dead === false && o.name !== player.name;
});
```

Comment: I found that this worked for what I needed, I didn't really understand how to use .filter and I think that now I understand it more. Thanks